# Ubuntu 15.10 x64, wine x32, pulseaudio - no sound

Tags: sound, wine, pulseaudio, alsa, playonlinux

I have ubuntu 15.10 x64 and wine x32 (playonlinux). No any sound in games (try hearthstone, C&C and etc). Try this http://oldwiki.winehq.org/WineAndPulseaudio, but zero effect. 
How I can fix it? 
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I manage it by myself. Here solution:

1. Basic advice - if you can use latest version of wine.
2. No need in http://oldwiki.winehq.org/WineAndPulseaudio. Just use winetricks - configure - and select audio to alsa.
3. If you use PlayOnLinux or etc you can run winetricks for separate wineprefix with command from terminal:

   `WINEPREFIX=/home/link0802/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/RA3 winetricks`

   **Where:**

   link0802 - your user. 
   RA3 - name of you wine drive/wineprefix

   **Once again select audio to *alsa* in *winetricks***
4. If audio still doesn't work try to uncomment/set **default-fragment-size-msec = 5** in **/etc/pulse/daemon.conf**. Run pulseaudio -k to restart pulseaudio.
5. If problem is still here try to remove package alsa-oss. Restart pulseaudio and try again.

*Additional:*
Sometimes you will need to run apps from wine with command line argument(for example to force game use some audio/video engine). In playonlinux you can do it like this:

1. Open you wine drive/wineprefix settings in playonlinux. Settings - select drive your drive - Miscellaneous - open shell.
2. Paste command in terminal 
   `POL_Shortcut "RA3.exe" "Red alert 3" "" "xres=1366 yres=768"`

   **Where:**

   "RA3.exe" - exe to execute. 
   "Red alert 3" - title for shortcut (second "" is desc)
   "xres=1366 yres=768" - command line arguments for exe (without "-")
3. If you use wine without additional software just type

   `wine myapp.exe -yourCMDargument`

Answer (score 0):

for normal debian repo `wine`

I ran:
`winecfg`
and then clicked the `Audio` tab, then selected `Pulseaudio` in all the dropdowns under the `Defaults` section.